# Xcode 'Deletes' Image View Inside Table View Based On Device Screen Size

Tags: ios, swift

I'm creating a simple app that includes a table view using Swift 5 and Xcode 11. Inside the table view(which, by the way, is fixed into landscape), there is a button on the right of the tableview cells and an image view with fixed constraints, size, and width on the left. Everything has been working out pretty well for my app, until I noticed that the image view would kind of 'disappear' if I changed the device to, for example, iPhone 5s, 4s, or even iPhone Pro(I'm testing with iPhone 11 Pro Max).

This is when the device is iPhone 11 Pro Max:
[11 Pro Max](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qtF59.jpg)

This is when the device is iPhone 11 Pro: [11 Pro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGuSj.jpg)

And here are my constraints for my image view: [Constraints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ieSCX.jpg)

Any help is appreciated
P.S. Ignore the image view that says 'img'

Comment: Hello can you also plz post the screen shot of the constraints you are using?

Comment: Just saw that also i noticed the Screenshot of 11 Pro and 11 Pro max the view are ordered differently and also in 11 Pro seems like the image view is hidden

Comment: I would also like to see the contraints for table view and if possible add screen shot from the right side panel `Size Inspector`

Comment: You can see the following answer which should solve your issues.

Comment: [You might find this useful for taking screenshots](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT201361) instead of using a camera.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After seeing both of the screen shots and the constraints I see what is the issue here.

It's the way you have applied the trailing constraint for the image which in your case is 663 (Should not be fixed). What you can try is Give width constraint to the image view and then change the trailing constraint something like below

[image: Sample constaints]

This should help you.
Also what you have to take care of moving forward is the constraints you choose to apply coz that is the most important thing while desigining Responsive UI

Happy Coding.

Answer (score 1):

right Constraint should be negative,for example,
img.snp.right = view.right - 20

Comment: In some cases this can be used , but in above requirements the user wants the image to left side of cell so it should have greater than equal to trailing constraints.

Comment: Or can totally remove the trailing and just give fix width to the image